# Error in ionic Caching, No such key (service directory)

Tags: angular, caching, ionic2

I am trying to incorporate caching into my ionic application. When I call the service however, I get the error

> Uncaught (in promise): No such key: http://serviceaddress.com/

I suspect that the error might be due to the groupkey which I pass to the function loadFromObservable() in the code below.

```
tutorList: any;
groupKey: 'tutors';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private cache: CacheService , public stallOwnerService:StallOwnerService){

}

ngOnInit(){
    console.log("on init has began");
    this.getPosts();
    console.log("On init ran");
}

getPosts(refresher?){
    let req = this.stallOwnerService.getPosts();

    let ttl = 5;

    if(refresher){

        let delayType = 'all';
        this.tutorList = this.cache.loadFromDelayedObservable(this.stallOwnerService.baseUrl, req, this.groupKey, ttl, delayType);


        this.tutorList.subscribe(data => {
            refresher.complete();
        });
    } else {
      this.tutorList = this.cache.loadFromObservable(this.stallOwnerService.baseUrl, req, this.groupKey, ttl);
    }
}
```

the code for the service looks like this

```
@Injectable()
export class StallOwnerService{
http: any;
baseUrl: string;
sponsorUrl: String;

constructor(http:Http){
    this.http = http;
    this.baseUrl = "http://serviceaddress.com/";
    this.sponsorUrl = "http://serviceaddress.com/sponsors";
}   

getPosts(){
    console.log("the output is as follows");
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl).map(res => res.json());
}
```

I have put the field "groupKey" in the database with value "tutors" so that the service returns objects with a groupKey field. I don't know if this is what is required for sure, but this is what they did in the example I read [here](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-caching-service/)  . What exactly is a groupkey and where do I put it, and is it what is giving me this error?

I am using ionic version 3.18.0 and ionic-cache 2.0.5

Comment: For me it was because I was referencing the function via a prop / binding on the HTML element. I moved my call to IonViewDidEnter() instead and it worked.